# "ere'" or "before"?

Tags: word-choice

I found "ere" was used a lot by Tolkien and some other authors. When can I use "ere" and when "before" in the following sentence?

> Let's go ere I change my mind

or

> Let's go before I change my mind

Is "ere" still used in English?

Comment: _ere_ is used quite a bit in poetry, and in some literary genres. It is no longer used in everyday writing or speech unless in jest. Both of your sentences are correct.

Comment: It's quicker if there's a dragon chasing you, of course.

Comment: As stated, both are grammatically correct. Currently, I'm researching the usage of the word *ere* and personally, I would be ecstatic to see people revive words of this sort. My research is so that I can properly argue that the revival of words similar to *ere* would help society regain the power of expression that they once had. Thus, I would emphatically endorse the usage of *ere*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oxford Dictionaries Online describes it as literary or achaic. For that reason, it is best avoided in normal contemporary speech and writing.

Comment: And certainly best not wrongly yoked with the more modern sounding 'Let's': _Let us set forth, ere I abandon this bold venture._